# Adding constraints of a specific data type in class declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, abstract-data-type

I have the following code exercise:

Create class Intern with next fields:
Name(String)
Surname(String)
laziness(number from 20 to 50)
Curiosity (number from 0 to 100)
Skill (number from 0 to 100)
Irresponsibility (float number from 0.0 to 1.0)
For this class create method that calculate “mark” for intern, that is calculated by formula

Question:
How can I add constraints to the original data type in a class? like int a, but in range from 20 to 50. or string. Here is my code without constraints:

```
class Intern {
constructor(name, surname, laziness, curiosity, skill, irresponsibility) {
    this.name = name
    this.surname = surname
    this.laziness = laziness
    this.curiosity = curiosity 
    this.skill = skill 
    this.irresponsibility = irresponsibility 
}
getMark() {
    let mark = (((this.skill+this.curiosity)*(1.5 - this.irresponsability))/(this.laziness*0.25));
   return mark
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would you like to happen if the given value is outside the constraints? Should the Intern get a default value?

I would make if statements for every attribute and check if the given value is bigger than the lowest constraint and smaller than the highest:

```
class Intern {
constructor(name, surname, laziness, curiosity, skill, irresponsibility) {
    this.name = name
    this.surname = surname
if(laziness<=50 && laziness>=20){
    this.laziness = laziness
}
if(curiosity<=100 && curiosity>=0){
    this.curiosity = curiosity 
    this.skill = skill 
    this.irresponsibility = irresponsibility 
}
getMark() {
    let mark = (((this.skill+this.curiosity)*(1.5 - this.irresponsability))/(this.laziness*0.25));
   return mark
}
```

the <= and >= operator checks if the value is smaller than or equal to or bigger than or equal to.

Comment: I would like just to show that a console.log that "invalid input range" and to exit the program. Kinda also don't know how to do it, I am a begginer in OOP so don't really understand it. sorry

Comment: You can type "throw 'invalid input range!';" in the else{} of the if statements that check if the value is above minimum and below maximum. But then you must also add a try{} and a catch{} where you call the constructor. 

I would not recommend this however. Better to make the value of the attribute 0 if it is outside the input range.